# Problems loading FinancialData

Tags: curated-data

When might Wolfram get FinancialData working again?
As of 9:30am Pacific time, this code:

```
FinancialData["RSP", "Name"]
Entity["Financial", "NYSE:RSP"]["Name"]
FinancialData["VSTCX", "Name"]
Entity["Financial", "VSTCX"]["Name"]
```

returns:

```
"Wildflower Marijuana Inc"
"Guggenheim S&P 500 Equal Weight ETF"
"Invesco Van Kampen Small Cap Value Fund Class A"
"Vanguard Strategic Small Cap Equity Fund"
```

The "wrong" answers were also recently returned using Entity.
Wolfram said FinancialData was "mostly working" last July.

The historical data for VSTCX also appears (to me) to be unlike the data for Vanguard's fund; so can the data for RSP be trusted?

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: Try FinancialData["NYSE:RSP", "Name"].  The information seems to be there in FinancialData, it's just parsing input in an unexpected way.